# Unable to append image src using closest img tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, attr

I am unable to append image src using the closest img tag.

When autocomplete option select i want to populate the image for that row

**HTML :**

```
<td>
    <div>
        <img class="participantphoto" src="images/author2.jpg" width="50" />
        <input placeholder="Type a letter to search students" class="form-control searchStudent formbottom" name="student[0][name]" type="text" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
</td>
```

**JS :**

```
$(document).on("focus keyup", "input.searchStudent", function (event) {
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: 'gdcontroller.php?action=search',
        select: function (event, ui) {
        console.log(ui);
            event.preventDefault();
            this.value = ui.item.label;
            // line below fails
            $(this).parent().closest( ".participantphoto" ).attr("src",ui.item.profile_pic);
        },
        focus: function (event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.value = ui.item.label;
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: $(this).parent().closest( ".participantphoto" ).attr("src",ui.item.profile_pic); is Not Working.

Comment: It's **well worth** your time to read through the jQuery API documentation for the methods you're trying to use (and just generally; takes an hour, two tops). [`closest`](http://api.query.com/closest) doesn't do what you seem to think it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`closest` starting from the `input` won't find the `img`, because the `img` isn't an *ancestor* of the `input`, it's a sibling.

As it's the only `img` sibling, `$(this).siblings("img")` finds it:

```
$(this).siblings( "img" ).attr("src",ui.item.profile_pic);
```

or if you want to use the class:

```
$(this).siblings( ".participantphoto" ).attr("src",ui.item.profile_pic);
```

Answer (score 2):

That not work because the img `.participantphoto` is not a parent of the input `.searchStudent`.

You should go to the closest div using `.closest('div')` then find the img tag with class `participantphoto` using `.find(".participantphoto")` and finally set the attribute `src` :

```
$(this).closest('div').find(".participantphoto").attr("src",ui.item.profile_pic);
```

Or you could use `.siblings()` instead :

```
$(this).siblings(".participantphoto").attr("src",ui.item.profile_pic);
```

Hope this helps.